# Unexpected GroovyCastException with Groovy and StreamAPI

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, java-stream, jenkins-groovy

I am running the following groovy script inside Jenkinsfile which is executed during the build:

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors
import java.util.stream.Stream
import groovy.transform.Field

@Field
Map<String, String> sampleMap = [
        'SampleKey1': 'SampleValue1',
        'SampleKey2': 'SampleValue2'
]

//example param value: "C/SampleKey1/someFile, C/SampleKey2/someFile2"
private Collection<String> getValues(String param) {
    Stream.of(param.split(','))
            .map { getValueFromOnePath(it) }
            .filter { !it.isEmpty() }
            .distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
}

private String getValueFromOnePath(String path) {
    String[] pathParts = path.split('/')
    if (pathParts.size() < 2) {
        return ''
    }
    return sampleMap[pathParts[1]] ?: ''
}
```

The expected result of the above code for parameter value equals to:

```
"C/SampleKey1/someFile, C/SampleKey2/someFile2"
```

is:

```
[SampleValue1, SampleValue2]
```

However, when this code is executed on Jenkins I receive a strange error which I cannot understand (why it occurs):

> hudson.remoting.ProxyException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'SampleValue1' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.Collection'
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.continueCastOnSAM(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:405)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.continueCastOnNumber(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:319)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.continueCastOnCollection(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:267)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.castToType(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:219)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:603)
>       at Unknown.Unknown(Unknown)
>       at ***cps.transform***(Native Method)
>       at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.LocalVariableBlock$LocalVariable.set(LocalVariableBlock.java:45)
>       at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.AssignmentBlock$ContinuationImpl.assignAndDone(AssignmentBlock.java:70)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor303.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
>       at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.LocalVariableBlock$LocalVariable.get(LocalVariableBlock.java:39)
>       at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
>       at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.LocalVariableBlock.evalLValue(LocalVariableBlock.java:28)
>       at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$BlockImpl.eval(LValueBlock.java:55)
>       at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock.eval(LValueBlock.java:16)
>       at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
>       at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
>       at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
>       at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:19)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:35)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:32)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:32)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:331)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$100(CpsThreadGroup.java:82)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:243)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:231)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
>       at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Any ideas?

Comment: Your code looks good. Don't know why, You can write it in plain groovy and try. 
param.split(',').collect { 
      List pathParts = it.split('/')
      pathParts.size() < 2 ? '' : sampleMap[pathParts[1]]
     }.unique()

Comment: Sure - I will try to write it without Stream API. However, I tested the same code locally and it works fine. When I execute it on Jenkins - then exception is thrown.

Comment: I changed implementation so I am using for loop instead of Stream API. It works fine now. But I really do not understand why it does not work on Jenkins with Stream API.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to annotate getValues with @NonCPS annotation. Also try to avoid using Streams inside code that is going to be executed in the Jenkins sandbox, that is often a cause of errors. Hope it helps.

Comment: I think you should give more information, because your problems so generally without images, code, more information...